# Writing to value at UnsafePointer<DSPSplitComplex>

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers, unsafemutablepointer

From what I understood, an UnsafePointer presents the pointee as immutable and an UnsafeMutablePointer presents the pointee as mutable. But the signature for the vDSP function [vDSP_zrvmul](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450657-vdsp_zrvmul) is as follows:

```
func vDSP_zrvmul(_ __A: UnsafePointer<DSPSplitComplex>, 
               _ __IA: vDSP_Stride, 
               _ __B: UnsafePointer<Float>, 
               _ __IB: vDSP_Stride, 
               _ __C: UnsafePointer<DSPSplitComplex>, 
               _ __IC: vDSP_Stride, 
               _ __N: vDSP_Length)
```

`__C` is supposed to be the output vector, but it's not mutable… what am I missing? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__A` and`__C` are pointers to 
[`DSPSplitComplex`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/dspsplitcomplex):

```
public struct DSPSplitComplex {
    public var realp: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>
    public var imagp: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>
}
```

which contain *mutable* pointers to arrays of floating point values.

`vDSP_zrvmul` writes the output  to the arrays pointed to by `__C.realp` 
and `__C.imagp`, but `__C` itself is not mutated.

Comment: OK, so the contents of the `__A` and `__C` pointers are references themselves; these references aren't changed (just their values), hence the immutability. Got it. Though I think the two properties here should be `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>`?

Comment: @Rogare: Yes, I mixed that up with DSPDoubleSplitComplex.